# Can I use Gödel numbers to make a proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

As we know, any proposition can translate to Godel numbers, such as 
$$( \exists x)\space (x=sy)$$Its Godel numbers is $2^8 × 3 ^4 × 5^ {13} × 7^ 9 × 11^8 × 13^{13} × 17^ 5 × 19^ 7 × 23^ {17} × 29^ 9=a \space big \space number $

We also could get the character sequence "$( \exists x)\space (x=sy)$" through prime factorization of this big number.

Such as$$243,000,000=2^6×3^5×5^6 $$
$$6\space\space\space\space\space 5\space\space\space\space\space 6 $$
$$\downarrow\space\space\downarrow\space\space\downarrow$$
$$0\space\space\space=\space\space\space 0 $$
So $243000000$ is the Godel numbers of "$0=0$"

There are four axioms in Godel's PM system, here are two of them:
$$(p\lor p)\subset p$$
$$p\subset (p\lor q)$$
through these two axioms, we can prove "$(p\lor p)\subset(p\lor q)$" is a true theorem.

And these two axioms and a theorem all have a corresponding Godel numbers, can we prove this theorem is true through Godel numbers? If it works, how?

Comment: For what it's worth, this number isn't the right number lol. There should be a lot more digits. There should be at least eight 0's on the end.

Comment: lol, thanks Alfred, I have edited it.

Answer (score 4):

Calculating the Godel number of a statement doesn't help us prove it at all - that's not the point. Rather, we can use Godel numbers to represent *claims about statements* as *claims about numbers*, and so in a sense "talk about math inside math." In particular, we can also give *proofs* Godel numbers (a proof is after all just a sequence of sentences with certain properties), and this lets us talk about (un)provability of statements about arithmetic - just using arithmetic itself!

For example:

> There is a formula $\varphi(x, y)$ of two variables in the language of arithmetic such that for all natural numbers $m, n$, the sentence $\varphi(\underline{m},\underline{n})$ is true - where $\underline{k}$ is the numeral corresponding to the natural number $k$ - iff $n$ is the Godel number of a proof from the axioms of PA of the sentence with Godel number $m$.

A deeper analysis of this situation then shows that we can in fact perform [a certain amount of self-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma), and this lets write sentences in the language of arithmetic alone that can be interpreted as saying "This sentence is not provable in PA" or similar; this is how Godel's incompleteness theorems are proved.

Comment: So though prime factorization of Godel numbers, we can't know a proposition is right or not?

Comment: No, the prime factorization just lets us translate a Godel number into a series of characters.  That series of characters might make a syntactically correct sentence.  In his paper, Godel shows how to build a function that says which numbers correspond to correct sentences.  He then shows how to build a function that says whether each sentence in a list is either an axiom or follows from previous sentences, which means the list of sentences is a proof.

Comment: @QiuhaoChen No, we cannot. All Godel numbering is is a *translation*: it translates statements, questions, and arguments about mathematical language into statements, questions, and arguments about arithmetic. Knowing the Godel number of a sentence doesn't help us prove or disprove that sentence any more than translating a math problem from English to Esperanto helps us solve it. The use of Godel numbers is rather that it gives us a way to "talk about math inside arithmetic," not that it helps us tell whether individual propositions are true or false.